# Cannot Select value from db where record contains dash ( ' - ' ) in node/express app

Tags: mysql, express

Im making node.js / express app and I want to use uuid to generate token.
the token contains the dash. When im trying to Select column where token is like fdda765f-fc57-5604-a269-52a7df8164e it doesnt work but when the token is like fdda765ffc575604a26952a7df8164e it does work. In addition i tried to type SQL query in PHPmyadmin panel and it returned my column where token was with dashes? Im using this module const mysql = require('mysql');

Also i found out when i pass value directly into query like this:

```
"SELECT CONFIRM FROM ORDERS WHERE TOKEN = 'd63d2-5a15-11ea-ae4d-79a508'"
```

and not with ? it also works.

here is my code

```
exports.getConfirmation= function(token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var sql = "SELECT CONFIRM FROM ORDERS WHERE TOKEN = ?";
    con.query(sql, [token], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        } else {
            return resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
        }
    });
  })
}
```

Any ideas how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: What is the type of the `TOKEN` column in the table?

Comment: could you `console.log(token)`? I guess there is something else in it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen TOKEN is varchar

Comment: @RolandStarke I placed console.log just before the query Here it is: bd968290-5c78-11ea-8c36-1fd2d7d29b05 
and gettiing error like that
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONFIRM' of undefined

Comment: If TOKEN is varchar, you're doing string comparison, it will not handle this kind of difference. You will have to format the parameter correctly. Can you show all the ways you tried and whether each one worked or not? There seems to be contradictory examples in your questions about what works or not works.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
var sql = "SELECT CONFIRM FROM ORDERS WHERE TOKEN = ?";
```

with

```
var sql = "SELECT CONFIRM FROM ORDERS WHERE TOKEN = '?'";
```

Comment: Token is a String an so you must set it '  else MySQL use it numeric. The Answer from Prakhar Londhe is correct

Comment: I' m afraid it is not correct answer, I am getting sql syntax error now like :                      sql: "SELECT CONFIRM FROM ORDERS WHERE TOKEN = ' '8ae57010-5c76-11ea-9429-2fd074272308 ' ' " . I believe that the question mark automatically inserts ' '

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this snippet helps to debug my code. I actually getting the token from req.params. Maybe it parses it in a wrong way

```
let tok = req.params.generatedToken;
db.getConfirmation(tok)
            .then((data) => {
                let confirmation = data[0].CONFIRM;
```

Im getting this TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONFIRM' of undefined